# Encrypt GPS coordinates in Postgis to safe guard user privacy if database is compromised

Tags: database, postgresql, security, postgis, privacy

Everyone knows to only store the salted hash of a user's password in the database.

**Are there similar standard practices about storing a user's GPS coordinates to prevent an attacker from knowing a user's location if the database is compromised?**

Specifically, I'm storing IoT device GPS coordinates using Postgis POINT using [SRID 4326](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system)

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.0, 0.0)'), 4326)
```

Comment: And how would salted hashing help with those queries?

Comment: It would not help, I think I said that clearly? Anyway, I've deleted that line to make the question a bit more focused.